# Extract a specific string from within a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need a regular expression to match a string within a longer string.
Specifically I need to not match any leading zeros or the last 2 digits for the string.

For example, my input might be the following:

`00009666666605
00010444444404
00007Z22222205
00033213433104
00009000G00005`

And I would like to match

`96666666
104444444
7Z222222
332134331
9000G000`

For further information, the last 2 digits are always numbers and describe the starting point of the valid reference, after the leading zeros.

I thought I'd cracked it with something like
`(?<=0000).{8}|((?<=000).{9})+?` but that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `I need a regular expression` why must it be a RegEx?

Comment: @djv I'm using an existing regex .net vbo throughout my process so much easier to add in another regex, rather than create an entirely new vbo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure takes a lot of steps, but this should do the trick:

```
(?<=^000)[^0].{8}|(?<=^0000).{8}

(?<=     'start lookbehind
   ^000  'for the beginning of the string then three zeroes
)        'end lookbehind
[^0]     'match a non-zero
.{8}     'match the remaining 8 chars
|        ' OR
(?<=     'start lookbehind
   ^0000 'for the beginning of the string then four zeroes
)        'end lookbehind
.{8}     'match the remaining 8 chars
```

That said, in .NET, it will be quicker to do:

```
dim trimmed = line.TrimStart("0"c)
dim numberString = trimmed.Substring(0,trimmed.Length-2)
```

if the format of these string is always the same

Comment: @ScottMeadmore Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. This will thank the poster and earn you a few points.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
^0*(.*).{2}$
```

And access your matches via `$1`

[Regex Storm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E0*%28.*%29.%7B2%7D%24&i=00009666666605%0D%0A00010444444404%0D%0A00007Z22222205%0D%0A00033213433104%0D%0A00009000G00005&o=m)

Comment: This one didn't work in .net using regex.match strangely

Comment: @ScottMeadmore Why did it fail for you?

Comment: This works and is much more efficient than the Regex you picked. You just have to handle the line feeds. It would be better to read each line in a loop (maybe `yield return` the match). Some thing like: `var sb = new StringBuilder(); foreach (string line in [Input[]]) { sb.AppendLine(Regex.Match(line, "^0+(.*).{2}$").Groups[1].Value); }`. If you want to treat text with `\r\n` as new line, then you could add a line feed at the end. Something like:: `string txt = [InputText] + "\r\n"; var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, "0+(.+).{3}");`